# Make localhost API Request with Symfony Client?

Tags: php, symfony, localhost

I am trying with Symfony 5 to make a request on my API developed with API Platform.

The URL in question is https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cheeses

When I do a GET request on it with Postman, everything works nicely. And if i'm going to the url in my browser, it works to. But impossible to make the request in PHP with Symfony. I went about it like this :

```php
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\HttpClientInterface;

class AbstractService
{

   public function __construct(private HttpClientInterface $client){}

   protected function request(string $method, string $path, array $params = [])
    {

        $response = $this->client->request('GET', 'https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cheeses', [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ]
        ]);

        dd(json_decode($response->getContent(), true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR));
    }

}
```

When I try it loops and I get the error :

> Idle timeout reached for "https://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cheeses".

But if I'm trying with external URL like **https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle**, it works.

My **nelmio_cors** config :

```yaml
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        origin_regex: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['GET', 'OPTIONS', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
        allow_headers: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
        expose_headers: ['Link']
        max_age: 3600
    paths:
        '^/': null
```

Any idea ?

Comment: How are you serving the application? What kind of server are you using? Is there a docker container involved?

Comment: I'm serving the application with `symfony serve`. Apache server, in local, and no, it's not a docker container

Comment: No idea, the SSL certificate might be the issue. It's the problem with  using the symfony CLI, it obfuscates part of the process.

Comment: I tested with SSL and without SSL and it's the same error

Comment: Hi. Try removing the https part of the request, just in case.

Comment: Hello, doesn't work, it says that scheme is missing :/

Comment: @eronn any update on this, I have the same struggle this is so upsetting.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the http request by **request forward** mechanism:

```
$response = $this->forward('App\Controller\yourController::methodName', ['name' => $name, // Your parameters... ]);

$content = $response->getContent();
```